# Не работает repeat...until

Tags: pascalabc.net

У меня в коде есть цикл repeat..until. Есть логическая переменная и переменная с ответом юзера. Проблема в том, что при введении любого ответа, кроме "да" (т.е. m := false), у меня происходит безобразие в консоли. 
А мне нужно просто "домучать" пользователя вопросами, чтобы он ввел "да". Как эту проблему можно исправить?

"Безобразие в консоли":

После ввода "нет" или "не знаю", эти сообщения у меня выводятся бесконечно и очень быстро.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
uses crt;

var
  a: string;
  m: boolean;

procedure NewPage;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 60 do 
  writeln();
end;

begin
  writeln();
  repeat
    writeln('Вам предлагается пройти тест на тему: "Окружающий мир".');
    write('Вы готовы пройти этот тест? (да/нет/не знаю) -->> ');
    read(a);
    m := false;
    if a = 'да' then
    begin
      writeln('Прекрасно. Начинаем.');
      m := true;
    end
    else if a = 'нет' then
    begin
      writeln('А кого это волнует? (с) Наталья Михайловна');
      m := false;
    end
    else if a = 'не знаю' then
    begin
      writeln('"Не знаю" приравнивается к "нет", Вы знали об этом?');
      m := false;
    end
    else
      begin
      writeln();
      writeln('Внимательно посмотрите на варианты ответов и выберите тот, который предложен!');
      end;
  until m = true;

end.
```

Comment: Строки читают с помощью ReadLn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
readln(a);
...
else
begin // !!!
  writeln();
  writeln('Внимательно посмотрите на варианты ответов и выберите тот, который предложен!');
end; // !!!
```

Comment: Да, ошибку исправил. Спасибо.
Но, к сожалению, не помогло(

Comment: @ЗлойШкальник "происходит безобразие в консоли" - что это значит?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, @Igor

Comment: @ЗлойШкальник Вы не исправили код.

Comment: только что, прямо скопировал Ваши изменения и вставил к себе в код. 
Все равно не работает. Отредактировал вопрос. Там у меня код, с теми изменениями, про которые Вы написали